# What is the best way to know the last time a MongoDB doc was changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

Do I need to tack on a `lastActivity: new Date()`  `@set` every time I interact with it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB currently doesn't have built-in functionality to set the last-updated date, so you have to do that yourself indeed. I would probably (depending on language) inherit the MongoCollection class to add a thin wrapper around this to do it myself.